# Unidirectional PHY transceiver

Tags: ethernet, rj45

I am trying to establish a unidirectional connection over a RJ45 cable (not an optical fiber). I saw in the IEEE 802.3 standard that the clause 66 describe how unidirectionnal chips should work. However, I do not find any chip that implement this clause. So here are my 2 questions :
- Do you know if there are some chips that are capable of establishing a unidirectionnal connection over a RJ45 cable?
- Is it possible to reprogram an existing chip?
Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using this connection?

Comment: Perhaps you don't find such chips because they would be useless for TCP which is 99% of IEEE 802.3 applications.

Comment: I just want to send data between 2 computers while one paired wire has been cut.

Comment: The use case would be to establish a secure network where you can only send data but not receive.

Comment: The problem is that most people sending data want to know that (a) the receiver is ready for it and (b) it's been received correctly. That requires a return connection for some sort of acknowledgement. Though I suppose you could use a UART at each end of the cable and just hope for the best.

Comment: You write "RJ45 Cable" but do you actually mean "Ethernet"? An "RJ45 Cable" could be used for almost anything - RS232/422/485, CCTV, anything-you-like, even Ethernet ...

Comment: It is possible to use 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX for unidirectional connections, I have seen an implementation with tranditional PHYs (one-way communications for data security). It is not possible with 1000BASE-T which uses all four pairs in both directions simuntaneously.

Comment: "Do you know if there are some chips that are capable of establishing a unidirectional connection over a RJ45 cable?" Sure, get some LVDS transmitters and receivers.

Comment: Even though it's about fiber rather than copper, much of the discussion under [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/297100/) still applies here.

Comment: Thnak you for your answers. I am currently looking at LVDS transmitters. 
brhans -> I am looking at all possibilities. The ideal would be Ethernet AND RJ45, but if there are solutions using Ethernet OR RJ45, I am also interrested.
TEMLIB -> This is precisely what I am looking for. Do you have any reference?

Comment: I finally found one : https://www.marvell.com/transceivers/assets/Marvell-88E3015-3018-Fast-Ethernet.pdf

Comment: Just cut the wires! Problem solved.

Comment: This does not work :) -> the PHY needs to receive activity signals to send data.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know if there are some chips that are capable of establishing a unidirectionnal connection over a RJ45 cable?

At least any IEEE 802.3-compatible 100BASE-TX-enabled PHY could be programmed via the MII Management Interface (MDIO/MDC) to support one-way connection. The target configuration is as the following:

- Disable Energy Efficient Ethernet (mandatory if supported)
- Disable Auto-Negotiation (mandatory)
- Force Full Duplex (mandatory)
- Force 100 Mbps Mode (mandatory)
- Force "permanent" Link Up (implementation-specific)
- Disable Auto-Crossover (Auto-MDI/MDIX, implementation-specific)
- Disable Far-End-Fault Generation (implementation-specific)
- Disable (any) Power Save mode(s)/feature(s) (implementation-specific)
- Disable (any) Cable Diagnostic feature(s) (implementation-specific)
- Disable (all) other smart feature(s) (implementation-specific)

Here "mandatory" means that the feature is defined by the Standard, "implementation-specific" means that the feature may be, if presents, specific to the particular choice.

One additional trick for the transmitting side PHY if all the above (suddenly) has no enough effect: connect the RX± pins of the PHY to the TX± pins of the PHY - before or after the transformer is case-dependent. If the PHY has no internal termination you have a chance to terminate such a "local loop" only once. There is no need in such the trick for the receiving side PHY of a planned uni-directional connection.

> Is it possible to reprogram an existing chip?

Yes, via MDIO/MDC if the chip you use is IEEE 802.3-compatible. The most (if not all) chips are.